# Clearing a component's Body in javascript throws error

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created component dynamically and tried clearing the body of the component by following code upon which I received below error.Please advise

```
component.set("v.body", []);
```

> rerender threw an error in 'markup://aura:expression' : body[j].$destroy$ is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in the code , below line was used to clear body of the component which was causing the issue.

component.set("v.body", "");

Comment: Makes sense. There is no type detection, so setting a component array to empty string makes sense to be error prone.